# passing url with space in GET parameter from Java servlet to Perl

Tags: java, perl

all

I have a java servlet program to invoke a perl and receive the data from perl. I used

```
String urlString = "http://[hostname]:[port]/cgi-bin/perl.pl?city="+city+"&chain="+chain;
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
InputStream urlStream = url.openStream();
```

as url to hit the perl, and for perl side, use

```
my $city = param("city");
my $chain = param("chain"); 
my $url_temp = "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Search?q=${chain}+${city}";
```

to grab the value of city in GET parameters

both servlet and perl work well with the name of city without space, however, for "Los Angeles" and "New York", I cannot come up with a solution to make it work.
I tried string.replace(' ','+'), it returns nothing; replace with %20 would make the program run into error

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You really should URLEncode the query string before appending it to the URL. Space will indeed be converted to `%20`. What error does the program give?

Comment: What do you mean I tried string.replace(' ', '+'), it returns nothing? Just if you forgot, remember that String are immutable, so you should do something like string = string.replace(' ', '+'). The actual good way to do all this is to use `URLEncoder.encode()` for your query params and query values which will amongst other things translate ' ' into '+'

Answer (score 0):

Like Konerak and Guillaume said, use url encode ...

```
// first
try {
   city = URLEncoder.encode(city, "UTF-8");
   chain = URLEncoder.encode(chain, "UTF-8")
} catch (Exception e) {}

// now your code
String urlString = "http://[hostname]:[port]/cgi-bin/perl.pl?city="+city+"&chain="+chain;
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
InputStream urlStream = url.openStream();
```